# Divmod() logic converting grams into kilos, pounds, ounces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert grams to kilos, ounces, and pounds. I'm having an issue to where if the total does not equal 1 ounce or 1 pound, the remainder grams aren't being counted because it's waiting for it to equal at least 28 or 448. Should I be using IF statements to fix this issue, or am I not using divmod() correctly?

```
total = 1027
kilos, pounds  = divmod(total, 1000)
pounds, ounces = divmod(kilos, 448)
ounces, grams = divmod(pounds, 28)

print('{} kilos, {} pounds, {} ounces, {} grams'.format(kilos, pounds, ounces, grams))
```

Result -
`1 kilos, 0 pounds, 0 ounces, 0 grams`

I want it to be - `1 kilos, 0 pounds, 0 ounces, 27 grams`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `quotient` part where you need to use the `remainder` in fact

```
total = 1027

kilos, pounds = divmod(total, 1000)
pounds, ounces = divmod(pounds, 448)  # pounds not kilos
ounces, grams = divmod(ounces, 28)    # ounces not pounds

print('{} kilos, {} pounds, {} ounces, {} grams'.format(kilos, pounds, ounces, grams))
# 1 kilos, 0 pounds, 0 ounces, 27 grams
```

---

Another with non-zeros values everywhere and a verification at the end

```
total = 2999

kilos, pounds = divmod(total, 1000)
pounds, ounces = divmod(pounds, 448)  # pounds not kilos
ounces, grams = divmod(ounces, 28)  # ounces not pounds

print('{} kilos, {} pounds, {} ounces, {} grams'.format(kilos, pounds, ounces, grams))
# 2 kilos, 2 pounds, 3 ounces, 19 grams
print(kilos * 1000 + pounds * 448 + ounces * 28 + grams)
# 2999
```

Comment: thanks, i knew i had something backwards. After messing with it for a while i was using `kilos  = divmod(total, 1000)` `pounds = divmod(kilos[1], 448)` `ounces = divmod(pounds[1], 28)` `grams = ounces[1]` which is basically your answer in a more complicated form lol.